# Using nbconvert to hide all input cells?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have a two cells in a Jupyter notebook, one which defines a function, and one which executes said function (I've provided a simplified function as of now). Currently, I include a bash command within the function to convert this notebook to a html file using nbconvert:

### Current output/notebook.ipynb

---

**Cell 1**

```
summary_gen(filepath):

    for summary in Path(filepath).rglob('*.txt'):
        txt= str(txt)

    print(bam)
    !jupyter nbconvert "/path/to/this/notebook.ipynb"
```

**Cell 2**

```
Summary_gen("/path/to/file")
```

- *Secondary: 1374881 + 0*
- *Supplementary: 0 + 0*
- *Duplicates: 0 + 0*

---

However, although I can output my entire notebook, *my goal is to use nbconvert to output a html which only contains the output of the function*, meaning when I run the function, I get a html like so:

### Desired output

---

- *Secondary: 1374881 + 0*
- *Supplementary: 0 + 0*
- *Duplicates: 0 + 0*

---

I think this is possible using some form of:

- `jupyter nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb -TagRemovePreprocessor.enabled=True --TagRemovePreprocessor.remove_cell_tags remove_cell`

or even the regex version:

- `jupyter nbconvert --RegexRemovePreprocessor.patterns="['some_pattern']" mynotebook.ipynb`

However, I admit I'm not entirely sure how to tag cells, or if there might be a better solution.

As always any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the argument `--no-input` to hide all the input cells in the output document.
You can just use it as:

`jupyter nbconvert --no-input notebook.ipynb`

You can also add `--no-prompt` to hide the prompts and have all the cells vertically aligned.

More information of the configurations options in the [docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html)