# JupyterLab print markup and outputs only

Tags: jupyter-lab

Perhaps this is too obvious but I can't find a way to do it: how can I print a JupyterLab notebook without the code? I only want to show markup cells and outputs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71997007/using-nbconvert-to-hide-all-input-cells and https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/removing_cells.html ?

Answer (score 0):

With my thanks to Krassowski for pointing me in the right direction. The answer is to use nbconvert from the command line thus:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html your-file-name.ipynb --no-input
```

And this generates your-file-name.html

For me, it didn't work the first time around. I got this error:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --to html testfile.ipynb --no-input
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook oppo.ipynb to html
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
AttributeError: module 'jinja2' has no attribute 'Markup'
```

If that happens to you, try this:

```
pip install --upgrade nbconvert
[...]
Successfully installed mistune-2.0.4 nbconvert-7.2.3 tinycss2-1.2.1
```

This worked for me. It case it helps, I am on jinja2 3.1.2.